# ASP.NET Web API - AutoMapper is not ignoring nullable booleans

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm writting web application in ASP.NET Web API and working on method to modify restaurant informations. The core entity is **Restaurant** that looks like this:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool HasDelivery { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
}
```

What is the most important in here - the `HasDelivery` property must be not-nullable. It has to take one of true or false value.
Next, I have **ModifyRestaurantDto** class which is given as a request from body while the app working. Just like the following:

```
public class ModifyRestaurantDto
{
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool? HasDelivery { get; set; }
}
```

To simplify I've just given a few of properties that are allowed to be changed. Note that all of them are nullable types.
I also have a service method called **UpdateAsync**, as follows:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(int id, ModifyRestaurantDto modifyRestaurantDto)
{
    var restaurant = await _dbContext
        .Restaurants
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id)
        ?? throw new NotFoundException("Restaurant not found...");

    var authorizationResult = _authorizationService
        .AuthorizeAsync(
            _userContextService.User,
            restaurant,
            new ResourceOperationRequirement(ResourceOperation.Update))
        .Result;

    if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded) 
        throw new ForbidException();

    _mapper.Map(modifyRestaurantDto, restaurant);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

What I want to achieve is to change only values which has been given in request body (in ModifyRestaurantDto). E.g. if my json body was looking like this

```
{
    "name": "Foo"
}
```

I wouldn't want Description and HasDelivery props to change.
Now, I've created AutoMapper profile and configured it inside Program.cs of course.

```
public class RestaurantMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public RestaurantMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ModifyRestaurantDto, Restaurant>()
            .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, value) => value is not null));
    }
}
```

And while given types are `string` everything works correctly. The problem is that nullable bool is always converted to false anyways. I'm using .NET 6.0 and have enabled Nullable and ImplicitUsings in .csproj.

Do you have some idea why only nullable booleans are not overlooked by AutoMapper?

Comment: So your issue is that when the map from modifyRestaurantDto --> restaurant is executed, not only the name is being updated, but the other two properties as well?Or the HasDelivery property is being updated as false when it does not have a value in the json?

Comment: The second one. But like Guru Stron noted it seems to be some AutoMapper bug.

Comment: AM is not designed for mapping to entitites. This has been discussed _many_ times before, you just need to workaround it. But this is not smth to "fix".

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu So what should I use for mapping to entities instead? What the best practices tell about it?

Comment: What you're doing is an anti-pattern called anemic domain model.

Comment: It's good to know, thank you! So what should I use for mapping to entities instead of AM to be in accordance with good practices?

Comment: You should have a proper domain model and then it wouldn't be automatic, so no tool would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug to me. A quick fix would be adding mapping from `bool?` to `bool`:

```cs
CreateMap<bool?, bool>().ConvertUsing((src, dest) => src ?? dest);
CreateMap<ModifyRestaurantDto, Restaurant>()
    .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((_, _, v) => v is not null));
```

Comment: Thank you, that really helped! I'm a little bit disappointed that AutoMapper has such bugs inside. I'm afraid the problem concerns all primitive types...

Comment: @BartTux yes, it should behave the same way for all value types.